# como puedo traducir es te codigo quicksort a pseudo codigo

Tags: javascript

alguien me podria explicar en pseudo codigo como funciona esta funcion lo entiendo hasta cierto punto pero luego me complico y termino sin entender. gracias

```js
 function quickSort( [ x = [], ...xs ] ){
   return ( x.length === 0 ) ? [] : 
    [...quickSort( xs.filter( y => y <= x ) ),x,...quickSort( xs.filter( y => y > x ) )];}n
```

Comment: Hola!, creo que el código que pusiste no creo que tenga mucho sentido, (O por lo menos yo no le veo el sentido),  ¿Tu intención era ordenar cada uno de los elementos de varios arreglos de forma ascendente y que te retornara un arreglo con todos estos elementos ya ordenados?, porque de por sí el código ya contiene algunos errores y cosas que no deberían estar ahí...

Comment: De hecho de por si intente probarla modificandole una sola cosa para que me funcionara (solo le quite los corchetes que encierran a los parametros de la función nada mas), (Pero no parece funcionar correctamente aún así), no realiza su función, que es la de organizar los valores.